# String to flask restful API from two different files

Tags: python, curl, flask, flask-restful

I have a task involving getting some data from a file to my flask API, I have two files with strings. 
One file data.txt, is just a file where each line is containing a json string, and another file containing the keys for each line in the data file.

I would like to post the data to my api, if it was just one single file i was able to do this by just doing

```py
data = request.get_json(force=True)
```

and just doing a curl request like the following

```sh
curl --request POST -d @data.txt 127.0.0.1:5000/data/input
```

But with two files, this approach didnt work, so i tried using the reqparser from flask_restful in the following way

```py
self.regparse.add_argument('data', action = 'append')
self.regparse.add_argument('key', action = 'append')
args = self.regparse.parse_args()

key = args['key']
data = args['data']
```

and i tried to use curl in the following way

```
curl --request POST --data-binary data=@data.txt --data-binary @keys.txt 127.0.0.1:5000/data/input
```

But that doesnt seem to work, any help would be appreciated

Comment: if you put snippets of the files, it might make it easier to understand what you're looking for. the number of rows in the data.txt file is exactly the same as in the keys.txt file?

Comment: Ah yes, I just thought that the layout of the file was not important since it's really only the lines that matter.

Yes the keys.txt has exactly the same number of lines